# Itô's lemma for semimartingale: $f(t,X_t)$ instead of $f(X_t)$, what is the formula?

Tags: integration, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

If $(X_t)$ is a continuous $d$-dimensional semimartingale and $f$ is $C^2$, we have Itô's lemma

$$f\left(X_{t}\right)=f\left(X_{0}\right)+\sum_{i=1}^{d} \int_{0}^{t} f_{i}\left(X_{s}\right) d X_{s}^{i}+\frac{1}{2} \sum_{i, j=1}^{d} \int_{0}^{t} f_{i, j}\left(X_{s}\right) d\left[X^{i}, X^{j}\right]_{s}$$

If we have $f(t,X_t)$ instead, I am tempted to say that the formula becomes

$$f\left(t,X_{t}\right)=f\left(0,X_{0}\right)+ \int_{0}^{t} \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}\left(s,X_{s}\right) d s+\sum_{i=1}^{d} \int_{0}^{t} f_{i}\left(s,X_{s}\right) d X_{s}^{i}+\frac{1}{2} \sum_{i, j=1}^{d} \int_{0}^{t} f_{i, j}\left(s,X_{s}\right) d\left[X^{i}, X^{j}\right]_{s}$$

Is this true ? Do you have a reference ?

Comment: Hint: Process $Y=(Id,X)$ is a $d+1$ dimensional semimartingale (where $Id$ is identity, i.e $Id(t)=t$) (in other words $Y_t = (t,X_t)$). Apply the result you know to it, together with $[Id,Id]_s = 0$ and $[Id,X^j]_s = 0$

Comment: Thank you! It was so obvious that I missed it